# Return records with only most recent TIME value?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a table I need to do some data conversion on. It is a simple tracking table as outlined below:

1. **SSN** 9,0 KEY (ex. 123456789) NON-NULL
2. **DATE** 8,0 KEY (ex. 20131202) NON-NULL
3. **TIME** 6,0 KEY (ex. 133000) NON-NULL
4. **PRINT_NEW** Z (ex.2013-12-02-11.23.47.965000) (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP used)
   NON-NULL
5. **PRINT_OLD** Z (ex. 2013-12-02-11.23.47.965000) (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   used) NULLABLE

Previously I was inserting the current system time into the [TIME] field, however, what I should have been doing is inserting the [TIME] field from the changelog I was joined to in processing.

As a start to this conversion, I am trying to select the [SSN], [DATE], [TIME] from my tracking table, and the [TIME] from the changelog (the value that [TIME] in my tracking table should actually contain).

The issue I'm having however is that the change log can have multiple entries, even on 1 particular date. For instance, my below attempt returns the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.SSN, a.DATE, a.TIME, b.TIME AS CORRECT_TIME
FROM            trackTable a, changeLog b
WHERE        (a.SSN = b.SSAN) AND (a.DATE = b.DATE)
```

Results:

```
SSN | DATE | TIME | CORRECT_TIME
123456789 | 20140117 | 94738 | 91541
123456789 | 20140117 | 94738 | 91542
678912345 | 20140123 | 124542 | 144557
678912345 | 20140123 | 124542 | 144558
678912345 | 20140123 | 124542 | 144559
678912345 | 20140123 | 124542 | 144600
```

My question is, how can I select only the MOST RECENT value for field [CORRECT_TIME]? I've been trying a few variations of joins and where clauses, but I'm still pretty new to SQL.

Comment: did you try to order by CORRECT_TIME limit 1 ?

Comment: I tried adding `ORDER BY CORRECT_TIME limit 1`, but it came back with an execution error: `Token LIMIT was not valid`. The tables reside on an IBM Midrange AS400 system if that helps?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 (...) ORDER BY CORRECT_TIME DESC?

Comment: @Ziouas, `SELECT TOP 1 a.SSN, a.DATE, a.TIME, b.TIME AS CORRECT_TIME
FROM            trackingTable a, changeLog b
WHERE        (a.SSN = b.SSAN) AND (a.DATE = b.DATE)` also yields an error...

Comment: Good question.  You included what you're after in plain language as well as the code you tried and the data you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

Try a Common Table Expression.  The 'with xxx as (...)' part will create a temporary table in memory so to speak.  The table will contain the latest time via MAX(TIME) for each unique combination of SSN and DATE via GROUP BY SSN, DATE.

Once you have the latest time for each SSN/DATE, you can JOIN back to it in your main query.

```
with latest as (select ssn, date, max(time) as latest_time from changelog group by ssn, date)
select t.ssn, t.date, t.time, latest_time
from tracktable t join latest l on t.ssn = l.ssn and t.date = l.date
order by t.ssn, t.date, t.time;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with tbl as (select ssan, date, max(time) as correct_time
             from changelog group by ssan, date
             )
select a.SSN, a.DATE, a.TIME, b.CORRECT_TIME
from tracktable a 
     join tbl b on (a.SSN = b.SSAN) AND (a.DATE = b.DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.SSN, a.DATE, a.TIME, b.TIME AS CORRECT_TIME
FROM            trackTable a, changeLog b
WHERE        (a.SSN = b.SSAN) AND (a.DATE = b.DATE)
ORDER BY CORRECT_TIME 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: That returns a single row, but I need the most recent time value from the changeLog table for EACH of the distinct SSN/DATEC combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window/analytic functions:

```
SELECT SSN, DATE, TIME, CORRECT_TIME
FROM (SELECT a.SSN, a.DATE, a.TIME, b.TIME AS CORRECT_TIME,
             max(b.TIME) over (partition by a.SSN) as MAX_CORRECT_TIME
      FROM trackTable a join
           changeLog b
           on  a.SSN = b.SSAN AND a.DATE = b.DATE
     ) ab
WHERE CORRECT_TIME = MAX_CORRECT_TIME;
```

First, note that I changed the `join` to use explicit `join` syntax with an `on` clause.  This is much better than the implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Second, this assumes that you want the latest time overall.  If you want the latest on each date, then change the `partition by` clause to `a.SSN, a.DATE`