# Remove duplicate values from ListView with the lower TIME value?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, duplicates, listviewitem

I have a listview control that is filled with returned records from a SQL Statement. The fields may be something like:

```
SSN------|NAME|DATE----|TIME--|SYS
111222333|Bell|20140130|121507|P
123456789|John|20140225|135000|P
123456789|John|20140225|135002|N
```

The "duplicates" are generated from a ChangeLog, such as a change of address. Due to bad database design I have no control over however, an address change will create 2 records if a member happens to be a member of both `SYS`.

What would be the best way to go through each record in my listview, find duplicate values of `SSN` & `DATE` (There can be a record generated for both `SYS` if person is a member of both), and remove the duplicate value with the lower `TIME` value?

I'm trying to do a code-based solution instead of SQL because the true SQL statement is already highly complex and this application needs to only be maintained until October.

Comment: Would it not be better to alter the SQL query?

Comment: ListView is a UI control and is not for manipulating data.  Why are you returning the duplicates in the first place?  You have asked this same question in SQL and have valid answers you have not accepted.

Comment: The SQL Query is already very complex compared to what is used as an example. @Blam, I'm not sure what you are referring to in SQL, but this is a different issue. The duplicates are returned due to bad database design that cannot and will not be anywhere soon corrected. I'm just looking for ideas for the best route to go about a solution through code.

Comment: Manipulate ListView is not the best route.  The best route is to not return duplicates.  Not related to this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045416/return-records-with-only-most-recent-time-value

Comment: @Blam, I understand it's not the best route. But given my experience with SQL I believe a code based solution would offer more maintainability until October when this particular application will be scrapped. As to the question you reference, similar issue I suppose, different ends. That question revolved around data conversion for the TIMEC field. The values weren't lining up, causing my PRINTED counts in the app to be way off. All of this is stemming from bad database design of keeping tables for the 2 separate systems, a design implemented long before I was here, and unlikely to change soon.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I've assumed you have some class with these record's properties exposed with easy access like `SSN` and `Time`, I've also assumed they were both strings. In the code below I refer to this object as `Record`.

HINT: You might instead want to be removing items with the `SYS` flag set to `False` instead of judging it on time (Probably doesn't make a difference) .

I did not used any lambda fun on purpose to try to keep this simple and easy to read.

Call this code every time you load items into the `ListView`.... it would actually be a better idea to sanitize that list before you load it into the `ListView`, but the below code is a solution to your question based on the available info.

```
//Turn the ListView's ItemCollection into an easy to use List<Record>
List<Record> records = myListView.Items.OfType<Record>().ToList();

//Grab records with duplicate SSNs but with lower Time values 
List<Record> recordsToRemove = new List<Record>();
foreach (var record in records)
{
    foreach (var r in records)
    {
        if (record.SSN == r.SSN && record != r)
        {
            if (int.Parse(r.Time) > int.Parse(record.Time))
                recordsToRemove.Add(record);
            else
                recordsToRemove.Add(r);
        }
    }
}

//Now actually remove the items from the ListView
foreach (var record in recordsToRemove)
{
    myListView.Items.Remove(record);
}
```